# What's with the reputation here on Stack Apps?

Tags: discussion, meta, reputation

This site is only a couple of hours old, yet there are 33 users with over 2000 rep and 9 with over 4000. Are these values holdovers from dev.meta.stackoverflow.com, where everyone started out with 4000 rep, or are these inflated rep values being given to users that actively participated in the private beta?

**edit:** This might be a candidate for a FAQ, as I probably won't be the only one to get confused about the rep levels on this site. However, should the FAQ remain here, where it's visible to new users, or should it be moved to Meta?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you participated in the private beta and produced actual apps/libraries, you got a gold badge and 4,000 reputation.

If you were in the private beta and got at least 1 up vote, you got a silver badge and 2,000 reputation.

See: https://stackapps.com/badges

To be clear. Nothing from dev.meta.stackoverflow.com gets copied over to stackapps.com. It is simply that if you participated in the beta, depending on the level of participation, you will get an appropriate badge.

Comment: What's the difference between "participated" and "actively participated"?

Comment: @Kyle I don't know. It might have been a difference between when you joined (there was an early and a later group of testers), or based on the amount of reputation you got during the beta duration. (I was in the top 5 out of around 50 testers)

Comment: @Chacha102 - How do we get the +2000 bonus for participating at all? I joined a few days ago, but it seems nothing I did on dev.meta has copied over.

Comment: @webdestroya Contact team@stackoverflow.com if you think you haven't been granted the badge and should have.

Comment: @Kyle considering the number of people that received the gold badge (10 at the time of writing), they might have chosen them manually, so there might not be a formal definition

Comment: Now I feel honored!

Comment: people who built (and shared) actual apps with the API in private beta qualified for beta gold. people who got at least one upvote qualified for beta silver.

Comment: @Jeff, I got silver beta badge before getting upvoted, asking or answering any question. A bug somewhere?

Comment: @juha I'm *LOOKING* at a post on dev.meta where you got upvoted on dev.meta .. so, I'd say you're misremembering.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood i remember participating in the private beta, specifically asking questions about the API, advising where to set up a private repository, etc.  I even posted about my StackKit framework and asked for helpers (and got some).  Does any of that count as "participation" or "active participation"?

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at the https://stackapps.com/badges page? Maybe you should...

Comment: I just did, and came here to answer my own question. Still, it was far from obvious.

Comment: I have more rep than Jeff. It is so nice.

Comment: @Chacha102: Let's vote him up a little bit, so he can enjoy reduced advertisement

Answer (score 3):

We draw the best circles.

Comment: Let's not turn this into meta, shall we?