# What constitutes 'active participation' in the private API beta?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

In trying to understand some [continued weirdness regarding badge/reputation rewarding](https://stackapps.com/questions/1383/why-has-the-badge-black-market-still-not-been-shut-down) in the context of private API participation I failed to find the explanation what exactly constitutes 'active participation', even though I recall that I read it somewhere sometimes. The [badges page](https://stackapps.com/badges) only states:

> `API Beta`: Participated in the private API beta; +2000 rep bonus
>   `API Evangelist`: Actively participated in the private API beta; +4000 rep bonus

Does someone recall or know what has been considered 'active participation'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it myself, in a comment on [Chacha102s answer](https://stackapps.com/questions/31/whats-with-the-reputation-here-on-stack-apps/33#33) to [What’s with the reputation here on Stack Apps?](https://stackapps.com/questions/31/whats-with-the-reputation-here-on-stack-apps) Jeff states:

> people who built (and shared) actual apps with the API in private beta qualified for beta gold. people who got at least one upvote qualified for beta silver

As this information has not been exactly easy to uncover I'll keep this posts for future reference and suggest to modify the explanation for these badges accordingly; the question itself can be marked `status-completed` though.

Comment: Hmmmm... not sure that's correct, because I was active in the private beta and didn't get anything. :(

Comment: @Dave - if I figure things correctly you have managed to get this issue sorted already, so my somewhat misguided ['investigation'](http://stackapps.com/questions/1383/why-has-the-badge-black-market-still-not-been-shut-down) had one positive outcome at least ;)

Comment: yep, i just got overlooked in the original pass through. things seem to be all taken care of now. :)