# What are the mechanics of private API beta badge/reputation rewards?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

**Update:**
George Edisons comments appear to explain most issues raised here (if not all), so I reformulated the question to reduce the noise and allow for an answer accordingly. I have considered to delete the question instead, but apparently it triggered one user to assess and resolve the lack of private API badge assignment to him, so there appear to be some useful outcome of my procrastinations at least ;)

**Background**:
I have been looking at this topic with the assumption that the private API beta worked just like the Stack Exchange 2.0 private betas, where all activities are at the target host starting from day one and only the access barrier is lowered over time. However, if I read things correctly now, the private API beta has been hosted on a separate site, which got migrated to Stack Apps later on with manual steps involved.

---

After one issue of [reputation inflation](https://stackapps.com/questions/1346/where-can-i-find-the-reputation-black-market) via multiple badge assignment [has been resolved recently](https://stackapps.com/questions/1346/where-can-i-find-the-reputation-black-market/1363#1363), I'm again confused by this topic due to the [introduction of the latest procrastination playground](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/) - the new [per-site reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues) do show for example:

- [Sorting by August](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/37/month/stack-apps/2010-08-01)

  - yields 1 user being rewarded the `API Beta` badge despite being a *member as of Aug 12* only
- [Sorting by June](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/37/month/stack-apps/2010-06-01)

  - yields 3 users being rewarded the `API Evangelist` badge, where some *don't have any posts before May 21* (start of public API beta) and some **don't have any posts at all** - see my related question [What constitutes 'active participation' in the private API beta?](https://stackapps.com/questions/1382/what-constitutes-active-participation-in-the-private-api-beta)
  - yields 5 users being rewarded the `API Beta` badge, where some are a *member as of May 21 or even June only*

Maybe the whole registration/membership has been reset after the private beta and the badges are triggered by the next visit only, but this doesn't explain the `API Evangelist` badges and could qualify as a confusing bug in the 'member for' display at least. Besides, looking at the [`API Evangelist` badges](https://stackapps.com/badges/60/api-evangelist) in isolation yields users with posts after May 20 only and **no posts or no activity at all even**.

Is it possible to get this explained/sorted without dissecting any case individually?

Comment: The API Beta badge is awarded when the user registers. I don't get your first point.

Comment: @George - the `API Beta` badge is rewarded to users that *Participated in the private API beta*; I presumed all those users have been migrated by default to Stack Apps, which implies anyone registering here later (i.e. after May 20) is not eligible for this badge. If all this is tracked elsewhere (as apparently done for the `API Evangelist` badge at least) and only triggers after a private API participator manually registers here at some point in the future, it would explain a lot already (if not everything), but I'm not sure that this is the case indeed?

Comment: @Stef: No, I participated in the private API which was before StackApps. The badges where hand-assigned and awarded *when the user first visited StackApps.*

Comment: @George - all right then, thanks much, this indeed explains most things; unfortunately I have to leave right now for a road trip, so I'll have to update my question on Sunday/Monday.

Comment: I want to get my API Beta badge reawarded! +2000 rep sounds *pretty nice* to me... (just kidding :D)

Comment: @George - I've reformulated the question to (hopefully) allow for an answer along the lines of your comments; I'll preferably accept yours but will add one myself in a couple of days if need be ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before StackApps, there was a small group of people privately testing the API. After some time, StackApps was created and everyone was notified so that they could move their content there.

A handful of people who had actively participated were hand-selected to receive badges. The badge was awarded as soon as the user registered on the site.

Comment: that's the truth :)

Comment: Also, the badges were awarded by OpenID. I registered on Stack Apps with a new OpenID and didn't get the badge until I associated my old one.