# Does Stack Apps have some special rep and Community Wiki modifications?

Tags: discussion, meta

I have posted a "question" (actually an app) on Stack Apps, and received two upvotes on it. Each gave me 10 reputation. This runs counter to every other Stack Exchange site - and, indeed, the Stack Apps help center:

> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> - question is voted up: +5

I've also noticed questions (like [this one](https://stackapps.com/q/36/21692)) that have run up **26 revisions by the OP** without any sign of auto-community-wikification (which normally kicks in at 10 revisions by the same editor). Something funny's happening; could someone explain what and/or why?

Comment: So, we gotta say +2 here at SA :) Nice Q and very good Answer it prompted, learned a couple of extra things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, stack​‌**apps** is different from any other StackExchange site in a variety of ways:

1. Most **"Questions"** are meant to be **announcement / product pages** for scripts, apps, and libraries.
   To this end, note:

   1. **Stack Apps has special tags**: [app](/questions/tagged/app), [script](/questions/tagged/script), and [library](/questions/tagged/library) to facilitate posting tools that use the API and/or enhance Stack Exchange sites.
      These posts *look* like questions but **they are not questions**.  In fact you will also see [support requests, bug reports, etc. posted as "answers"](https://stackapps.com/a/2005/7653) -- without getting flagged or downvoted.
   2. Questions accept and use **Magic formats**. See ["How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here"](https://stackapps.com/q/7/7653).
2. Tools have **Special listings**, unlike any other site.  For example, see [the script listing page](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script?sort=votes&pageSize=50).  Note that many scripts have thumbnails and, often, custom blurbs:
   [(Click for larger image)

   [image: Listing page]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyaJq.gif)
3. [*Stack Apps* is **its own meta site**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/60099/148310).
4. [The main page](https://stackapps.com/) **lists "Top Apps"**, not "Top Questions".
   [(Click for larger image)

   [image: Main page is different]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRNup.gif)
5. There have been [other **reputation exceptions** for Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/31/7653).
6. Since "payload" questions aren't questions here, [**the Community Wiki switchover is relaxed**](https://stackapps.com/q/221/7653).

---

## In a nutshell:

1. Here at Stack Apps, **the main purpose is to post solutions** for, or using, Stack Exchange sites.
2. For coding ease, the question/answer format of other SE sites was shoehorned for this purpose, but "questions" properly tagged as [app](/questions/tagged/app), [script](/questions/tagged/script), or [library](/questions/tagged/library) are not questions, they are answers and tools for public use.  They deserve their full 10 points per vote.

   **[The Reputation help page](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-reputation) should be fixed, for Stack Apps.**
3. The other questions on this site (that aren't announcing apps) theoretically should only get 5 points.  But this is, no-doubt, not worth the trouble to try and code.