# Which reputation events are private?

Tags: support, api, documentation, reputation, events

I've been reading [the API documentation on retrieving a user's reputation history <sup>(docs/types/reputation-history)</sup>](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation-history)
and [Stack Overflow's description of how reputation is calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

But, I can't find the current policy on which reputation events are public versus private.
Is there a page that describes the current policy and/or which reputation events are private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a place that describes the policy.  [That API-object, documentation page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation-history) would be perfect for it.

However, [a lead Stack Exchange developer has stated that **anything that reveals voting patterns will be hidden** or private.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85546/148310)

[Another Stack Exchange employee explains how user deletions and post deletions are kept private-ish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81391/148310), but experimental observation shows that this may not carry over into what the API treats as private. (`post_deleted` is private, while `user_deleted` is public, for example.)

Here are the reputation event types and their private (need to be authenticated and visible only to the user in question) status, as experimentally determined:

```
Reputation History Type             Public/Private?
--------------------------------    ---------------
answer_accepted                     public
answer_unaccepted                   public
arbitrary_reputation_change         public**
asker_accepts_answer                public
asker_unaccept_answer               public
association_bonus                   public
bounty_cancelled                    probably public?
bounty_earned                       public
bounty_given                        public
post_deleted                        private
post_downvoted                      public
post_flagged_as_offensive           probably private?
post_flagged_as_spam                probably private?
post_migrated                       probably private?
post_undeleted                      does not appear?***
post_undownvoted                    public
post_unupvoted                      public
post_upvoted                        public
suggested_edit_approval_received    public
user_deleted                        public
vote_fraud_reversal                 probably private?
voter_downvotes                     private
voter_undownvotes                   private
```

Notes:

- ** In at least one case, anyway -- [the special private beta bonus for this site](https://stackapps.com/a/33/7653).
- *** Looked in a couple of cases where rep changed due to undeletion, but this event did not appear in either the public or private API routes.
- The events with (?) could not be found by me. I don't recommend attempting spam or vote fraud to test those, either. ;)